# "All attempts at unauthorized access" VS. "all attempts of unauthorized access"

Tags: prepositions

> The system logs all attempts **of** unauthorized access;

Would this be grammatical? It feels to me that it's better to use **at**:

> The system logs all attempts **at** unauthorized access;

But I can't find online whether it's still grammatical to use **of** here. Judging by a Google Ngram search, there are no instances of "attempts **of** unauthorized access". Does that mean that **of** is always wrong in this case?

Comment: The most common nouns to precede ***unauthorized access*** are ***risk, prevention, possibility, threat, type, likelihood,...*** - all of which would naturally use the preposition ***of***, whereas ***attempts*** are usually made ***at*** something. Maybe most technical writers use *The system logs all **attempted** unauthorized access* to avoid needing a preposition at all. Anyway, it's still a kind of "access" if a hacker got as far as being logged (and presumably blocked from doing anything else).

Comment: *All attempts to access the system are logged.* One would presume that authorised access is logged too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Attempts at" is more idiomatic, as shown by your own ngram research. Unless you have a reason to insist on "attempts of", you should stick with the usual expression. It's not a question of grammaticality but of customary usage.
 Prepositions are peculiar in that they don't always have exact meanings in themselves, but acquire it in customary uses.